# which editor to be used for web development for hybrid app?

Tags: reactjs, editor, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am about to start project which needs to be an hybrid app. Mobile developers wants to do it using react native. As a backend developer, i need to implement website.

Which editor should i use to develop web panel for a hybrid app (using react native)?

Comment: Sorry, but this question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow, because it solicits subjective opinions. Though the correct answer is obviously Vim. :P

Answer (score 0):

Go for [visualstudio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for app development and make sure to install supporting extensions for react native app development.